# How to use Sqlite with ionic 2 rc.0?

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2

I would like to know how to use Sqlite with Ionic 2 rc.o release.I am finding it difficult as there are no examples for the latest version release and i am stuck.Nothing on the net seems to be updated.A supporting example for Sqlite would be of great use.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you solved or not yet? https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: Nopes @mosca90 i am on the same page.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if is working? @Hrishikesh Kulkarni

Answer (score 7):

1) First of all, navigate to the root folder of your project and add the plugin:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
```

2) Create a new provider inside the project (in this example, called **SqlStorage**):

```
$ ionic g provider sqlStorage
```

3) I'd like to add an import to **app.component.ts** to initialize the plugin at startup, not mandatory:

```
import {SqlStorage} from '../providers/sql-storage';
...
...
constructor(public sqlStorage: SqlStorage){}
```

4) Add entry to **app.module.ts**, mandatory:

```
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { SqlStorage } from '../providers/sql-storage';
...
...
providers: [SQLite, SqlStorage]
```

5) Define the **sql-storage.ts** provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@Injectable()
export class SqlStorage {

    storage: any;
    DB_NAME: string = '__ionicstorage';

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public sqlite: SQLite) {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            this.sqlite.create({ name: this.DB_NAME, location: 'default' })
                .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                    this.storage = db;
                    this.tryInit();
            });
        });
    }

    tryInit() {
        this.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kv (key text primary key, value text)')
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Unable to create initial storage tables', err.tx, err.err);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Perform an arbitrary SQL operation on the database. Use this method
     * to have full control over the underlying database through SQL operations
     * like SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE.
     *
     * @param {string} query the query to run
     * @param {array} params the additional params to use for query placeholders
     * @return {Promise} that resolves or rejects with an object of the form 
     * { tx: Transaction, res: Result (or err)}
     */
    query(query: string, params: any[] = []): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                this.storage.transaction((tx: any) => {
                        tx.executeSql(query, params,
                            (tx: any, res: any) => resolve({ tx: tx, res: res }),
                            (tx: any, err: any) => reject({ tx: tx, err: err }));
                    },
                    (err: any) => reject({ err: err }));
            } catch (err) {
                reject({ err: err });
            }
        });
    }

    /** GET the value in the database identified by the given key. */
    get(key: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.query('select key, value from kv where key = ? limit 1', [key])
        .then(data => {
            if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
                return data.res.rows.item(0).value;
            }
        });
    }

    /** SET the value in the database for the given key. */
    set(key: string, value: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.query('insert into kv(key, value) values (?, ?)', [key, value]);
    }

    /** REMOVE the value in the database for the given key. */
    remove(key: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.query('delete from kv where key = ?', [key]);
    }
}
```

6) In your **.ts** page:

```
import {SqlStorage} from '../../providers/sql-storage';

export class ExamplePage {
    constructor(public sqlStorage: SqlStorage) {
        // this.sqlStorage.query(...);
        // this.sqlStorage.get(key).then(data => {
        //    console.log(data);   
        // }
        //...
    }
}
```

Credit to: https://github.com/NickStemerdink with some personal changes.
Hope it will help and works fine :)

**EDIT:** Still works fine with Ionic v3.0.1 (2017-04-06)

Comment: You forgot to change `this._db.transaction...` to `this.storage.transaction...` in your query function. And I'm new to this but running the code gives me a Runtime error: "Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]" using `this.sql.set(...)`.

Comment: Thx, forgot to change that!

For insert and update, if not working, try something like this:
`updatePackage(id: number, nota: string, data: string, time: string): Promise<any> {
return this.query('UPDATE package SET nota = \"' + nota + '\", dtaVar = \"' + data + '\" WHERE id = ?', [id]);
}`

Comment: @mosca90 is the purpose of the 6th point i mean this line `this.sqlStorage.query(...);`

Comment: this is how you call the sql provider from your .ts page! @Mohan Gopi

Answer (score 1):

**in app.module.ts**

```
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

 providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        SQLite,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
    ]
```

**in database provider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the Database provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Database {

    DB_NAME: string = 'ssddb';

    constructor(public http: Http, public platform: Platform, public sqlite: SQLite) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.configureDatabase();
        });
    }

    configureDatabase() {
        this.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMP (key text primary key, value text)')
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Unable to create initial storage tables', err.tx, err.err);
            });
    }

    query(query: string, params: any[] = []): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                this.sqlite.create({
                    name: this.DB_NAME,
                    location: 'default'
                })
                    .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                        db.transaction((tx: any) => {
                            tx.executeSql(query, params,
                                (tx: any, res: any) => resolve({ tx: tx, res: res }),
                                (tx: any, err: any) => reject({ tx: tx, err: err }));
                        })
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.log(e));
            } catch (err) {
                reject({ err: err });
            }
        });
    }

    get(key: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.query('select key, value from EMP where key = ? limit 1', [key])
            .then(data => {
                if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
                    return data.res.rows.item(0).value;
                }
            });
    }

    set(key: string, value: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.query('insert into EMP(key, value) values (?, ?)', [key, value]);
    }

}
```

**in page.ts**

```
        this.database.set("333","ss");

 this.database.get("333").then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: data,
                duration: 10000,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
            toast.present();
        });
```

Comment: Good example, but you should explain exactly what is going on, instead of just posting code.

Comment: yes i agree with Adam i am still struggling in this if you could give me some example it would help me @Musa Sheikh

Comment: Are you opening/creating the database on each call to `query`?

Answer (score 0):

On [ionic-storage repo](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage) they say to use [Ionic Native SQLite plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/).
So like this:

```
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

SQLite.openDatabase({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLite) => {

    db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {}).then(() => {}).catch(() => {});

  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error opening database', error));
```