# ionic 2 Storage & Database data getting lost once kill the app in Android

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 SqlStorage for storing some data. but it is getting lost once kill the app in android devices.

The following sample code for storing data.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
  private storage: Storage;

  constructor() {    
    this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
    // we're creating a table called 'devicedata' if it doesn't exist
    this.storage.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS devicedata (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, institutionid TEXT, userimage TEXT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, email TEXT, dob TEXT, gender TEXT, aadhaarno TEXT, nickname TEXT, mobile TEXT, geocode TEXT, location TEXT, ip TEXT, type TEXT, deviceid TEXT, os TEXT, app TEXT, capability TEXT)');
    this.storage.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS seqquestions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, seqques TEXT, secseq TEXT, status TEXT)');
  }

  saveDeviceData(data) {
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO devicedata (institutionid, app, capability) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    // return the query which happens to be a promise.
    return this.storage.query(sql, [data.institutionid, data.app, data.capability]);
  }    

 // get all categories
  getDeviceDetails() {
    return this.storage.query('SELECT institutionid, userimage, firstname, lastname, email, dob, gender, aadhaarno, nickname, mobile, geocode, location, ip, type, deviceid, os, app, capability FROM devicedata');
  }
    updateProfileDetails(obj){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
      let sql = 'UPDATE devicedata SET nickname = ?, userimage = ?, firstname = ?, lastname = ?, email = ?, dob = ?, gender = ?, aadhaarno = ?';
      return this.storage.query(sql, [obj.nickname, obj.userimage, obj.firstname, obj.lastname, obj.email, obj.dob, obj.gender, obj.aadhaarno]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I'm using sqlite plugin and works fine. Maybe give it a chance: [SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40398191/6120917)

Comment: I'm wondering if you found a solution for this question?