# Cordova SQLite Plugin: No data after restarting application on Android

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I have a quite strange problem. I am using the Cordova SQLite plugin with Ionic2.
Using the app in chrome, when I save data in my tables, the data is still there after restarting the app.
But when I restart the app on android (closing and reopening it, so not just sending it to background), the data is gone. 
Is there maybe a known issue?

I can provide you with more information when needed. Trying to find the bug for the last six hours...

Best regards

Comment: Maybe a bad implementation?
Check here if you are doing it right :)
[SQLite plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277905/how-to-use-sqlite-with-ionic-2-rc-0/40398191#40398191)

Comment: I tested it with an empty Ionic project. There seems to be a bug in the SQLite implementation, I discussed it with the developer of the plugin, who basically confirmed that.