# SQLite vs LocalStorage with Ionic/Firebase

Tags: ionic2

I am writing a chat app in Ionic 2.  I want to save some of the the messages locally on the phone.

I am using Firebase as the messaging system. It stores the messages in JSON notation. When I read a message I want to store it locally and delete it from Firebase

Should I use SQLite or Local Storage?

I would normally say SQLite bexcuse it's more reliable, but because Firebase uses JSON, should I rather store the local messages as JSON in Local Storage?

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: For more sql like query, i preferred sql lite. Here you can find an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277905/how-to-use-sqlite-with-ionic-2-rc-0

Comment: Did you implement this? How did you load the chats from cache and then replaced it with fresh Firebase data once the data is transferred?

Answer (score 6):

Because you are using Ionic, I would suggest that you use the [ionic-storage](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage) module.

By default it uses the most advanced storage mechanism available. So in Chrome, it will use IndexedDB and fall back to WebSQL or LocalStorage.

If you install the `cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin, ionic-storage will use sqlite as the storage engine when running on the device.

You can only store key-value pairs using ionic-storage, so you can't use custom sql-queries. But storing JSON works without any modifications.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds exactly what I am looking for. Simple and robust and can store JSON.