# Using Ionic storage or a database (NoSQL, Sqlite, etc)

Tags: ionic-framework

I am going to create an app (iOS and Android) that will save data to the users device (text, images, files, etc) and will stay on the users device until they decide to send it to the server. I can do it either with a sqlite database or using ionic storage but I don't know what the best practice would be

For simplicity I will only present two types of items that will be stored - `notes` and `records`

notes structure

```
notes = { 
     description: this.description,
     'otherText': this.otherText,
     fileOrImage1: this.imageOrFileURL1,
     fileOrImage2: this.imageOrFileURL2,
    ..... Unlimited number of fileOrImageURL'S here
};
```

records structure

```
records = { 
     name: this.name,
     'description': this.description,
     // NOTE: These files and images are different than the ones above. They will be in separate components 
     fileOrImage1: this.imageOrFileURL1,  
     fileOrImage2: this.imageOrFileURL2,
    ..... Unlimited number of fileOrImageURL'S here
}
```

The user will first store the data on the device and it will only get uploaded when the user sends it to the server. Once its uploaded it gets deleted.

There can be many notes and records, lets say 25 each. Should I use `Ionic Storage` or something like a sqlite database? If I use ionic storage I will need to create a unique ID for each note and record and save it.

I am willing to change my approach if anybody has a better way. I'm still in the planning stage

Comment: There are 2 similar posts for this topic. Have a look:  1. [ionic storage vs native storage](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-storage-vs-native-storage/74958)     2. [sqlite vs localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573983/sqlite-vs-localstorage-with-ionic-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

I used the sqlite database for an app I did with Ionic, the reason for my choice was that I could then easily query the data, as with any database.