# SqlStorage deprecated with ionic3. How to use SQLite plugins with ionic serve

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

We are developing a cordova based mobile app with angular4 and ionic3. The issue is with the usage of cordova based SQLite plugin.

I am unable to run the SQLite native plugin with ionic server through the browser. It complains native plugins not available. I tried adding old Storage and SQLStorage typescript files from Old Ionic 2.0.0 RC version to new one. But the new version of ionic is complaining the constructor call.

Issue is with navigating through screens based on the data persisted in storage.

Can somebody please suggest how to debug this app on browser? Is there any other way I can try to resolve this. Not sure how to locate the SQLite storage device on Android filesystem.

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'offline.db',
        location: 'default'
      }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USR(USR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,SALUTATION TEXT, FIRST_NAME TEXT, LAST_NAME TEXT,'+
          'USR_NAME TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, USR_PWD TEXT,SESSION_ID TEXT)', {})
            .then(() => console.log('Executed USR_MST SQL'))
             .catch(e => console.log(e));          

        })
        .catch(
          e => console.log("Cordova excecution failed.. "+e));

        });
```

Comment: can you add the code where you are getting error?

Comment: hi, due to formatting issues updated the code in the main thread

Comment: Tried adding platform browser, but database not created in browser.

Comment: actually you should be editing your main question itself.. You should use _Post An Answer_ for answering questions only..

Comment: _I tried using old storage_ You mean @ionic/storage?

Comment: import {Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular'; This is from old version of   "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.9",

Comment: I think you can't run this plugin through the browser, try with a real device...
And for use of sqlite plugin, you can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277905/how-to-use-sqlite-with-ionic-2-rc-0)

Comment: Is there a way we can use websql with ionic3? I think websql will use android storage incase of app. This way it is easier to work with ionic serve. For testing with real devices best way to log is console.log?

Comment: @jslearner07 http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: @suraj thanks.I have already tried. I need tables, storage is for key and values.

Comment: if you want to use ionic native you wont be able to test with browser..

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work for me in android device as well. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874099/ionic3-with-sqllite-on-select