# Ionic3 with sqlite- on select

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, angular, ionic3

I have issue with querying the records from SQL Lite DB using cordova in Android

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'temp.db',
            location: 'default'
          }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

           console.log('Querying for temp user '+user.userName+'Password '+user.password);

           console.log('User queried'+user.userName);

            db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM USER  where USER_NAME = ? and USER_PWD=?", [user.userName,password]).then(
            response  => {
              let records='';
              for (let i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
                records = records+ JSON.stringify(response.rows.item(i))+'\n'; //Prints row correctly
              }
             this._util.presentAlert('Records selected like from- USR-',records);
            })
         .catch(
            e => this._util.presentAlert('Fail- Select like from- USER-Temp DBUSER',e));

            db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM USER  where USER_NAME = ? and USER_PWD=? ", [user.userName,password ]).then(
               response => {
                if (response && response.rows && response.rows.length > 0) {


                    for (let i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
                            let access = { 
                                firstName :response.rows.item[i].FIRST_NAME, //This is undefined.
                                lastName :response.rows.item[i].LAST_NAME,
                                userName:response.rows.item[i].USER_NAME,
                                userId:response.rows.item[i].USER_ID
                              }

                             observer.next(access);

                      }

                      observer.complete();

                } else {
                  let access = {status:'Fail',msg:'Bad credentials for Temp DB login'};
                 console.log('No record for the user from- USER'+user.userName);
                  observer.next(access);
                  observer.complete();               

                }
              })
              .catch(
              e => {
               console.log('Fail- Select query gone wrong * from- USER FOR Temp DB LOGIN' + e);
                let access = {status:'Fail',msg:'Bad credentials for Temp DB login'};
                observer.next(access);
                observer.complete();

              });
```

The issue is this one is printing the records correctly

```
JSON.stringify(response.rows.item(i))
O/P
{'USER_ID':1,'FIRST_NAME':'Temp','LAST_NAME':'User','USER_NAME':'TEMPUSER','USER_PWD':'TEMPPWD'}
```

Below is throwing undefined error

```
firstName :response.rows.item[i].FIRST_NAME
Fail- Select query gone wrong * from- USER FOR Temp DB LOGIN TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIRST_NAME' of undefined
```

Why am I unable to fetch it as as JSON?

Comment: Can you try again with `user.password` in spite of `password` in your queries?

Comment: No actually password is encrypted. So I am using a new variable.But if u see here  when i alert below statement it works fine and gives the json. records+ JSON.stringify(response.rows.item(i))+'\n'; . Issue is only when i use :response.rows.item[i].FIRST_NAME

Comment: console.log('user found in DB-->Response item type'+typeof(response.rows.item[i])); gives the type as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the issue. Incase if it helps anyone

```
1.Removed cordova sqllite plugin
2.Reinstalled Ionic sqllite plugin -latest
3.Took npm update of cordova
4.Performed cordova prepare android
5.Executed ionic build android
6.Corrected the typo from the queries response.rows.item(i).FIRST_NAME. It should be curly brace only. Sadly IDE doesnt trigger any error
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how late it is, but you must use:

```
response.rows.item(i).FIRST_NAME
```

() instead of [].