# ionic 3: How to use storage(Sqlite) plugin

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2, storage, ionic3

I have created login screen and home screen i have an object with three data which have to be stored using sqlite how to do that i am not getting any idea

```
{
      "userId": "",
      "loginId": "",
      "passwd": ""
    }
```

I have created an provider where my sqlite store code goes

```
export class SqlStorage {

  constructor(public http: Http,private sqlite: SQLite) {
    console.log('Hello SqlStorage Provider');

    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('create table kmartIndia(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
      .then((db) => { 
        console.log('Executed SQL');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    });
  }

  setValue(){}

  getValue(){}

  removeValue(){}
}
```

> i don't know how to make it work
>
> how to create a table and how to set, get and delete the value i am not very familiar with this any help.

Comment: @mayur i saw that one i am not able to understand where it is creating and how to set the object into the table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277905/how-to-use-sqlite-with-ionic-2-rc-0 here you are, check this, thx!

Comment: @mosca90 i am not understanding your 6th point

Comment: this is how you call the sql provider from your .ts page! @Mohan Gopi

Answer (score 0):

after some digging i found how to make this work.

It seems that the "create" method is used for both creating and opening a database.

In yout setValue() do:

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
  db.executeSql("insert into kmartIndia(name) values ('Mohan')", {}).then(() => yourVariable = 'Executed SQL').catch(e => yourVariable = e);
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

And, to get data from the table:

```
this.sqlite.create(
  {name: 'data.db', location: 'default'}
  ).then(
    (db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('select * from kmartIndia', {}).then( 
        (data) => {
          for(var i =0; i< data.rows.length;i++){
            yourVariable += data.rows.item(i).name
          }
        } 
      )
    }
  );
```

(I assigned the value with +=, but it's just and example :) )