# TypeError: this.sqlites.executeSql is not a function

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic3

Hi we are creating on hybrid mobile app. We are trying to save data into `SQLite` using Ionic3 & Angular4. So we add plugin to our project then we tried like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    sqlites:any = null;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public plt: Platform) {
        this.sqlites = new SQLite();

        this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
        this.sqlites.create({
            name: 'userInfo.db',
            location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usernameList(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,age NUMBER,address TEXT,education TEXT)', {})
            .then(() => alert('Executed SQL'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });

}


    user = {};

    save(user){
        this.sqlites.executeSql('INSERT INTO usernameList(name,age,address,education) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', [user.username,user.age,user.address,user.education])
        .then(()=>alert("insertFine"))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }

}
```

In above code we are creating table in `constructor` it's working fine then we tried to insert data into table using save button action. But we are getting error ERROR

```
TypeError: this.sqlites.executeSql is not a function. (In 'this.sqlites.executeSql', 'this.sqlites.executeSql' is undefined) — main.js:183
```

Please guide us. What do we miss?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277905/how-to-use-sqlite-with-ionic-2-rc-0/40398191#40398191).
And you should put the sql logic in a provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `this.sqlites` is of type `SQLite`. Which doesn't have a method `executeSql`. An `SQLiteObject` on the other hand does.

You should inject `SQLite` in the constructor:

```
export class HomePage {
    // If you inject SQLite in the constructor you dont have to declare sqlites 
    // here
    // sqlites:any = null;

    constructor(private sqlites: SQLite) {
    ...
```

You can store the `SQLiteObject` that is returned from this:

```
this.sqlites.create({
    name: 'userInfo.db',
    location: 'default'
})
.then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    this.db = db;
    ...
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your class, like in the `save()`-function:

```
save(user){
    this.db.executeSql('INSERT INTO usernameList(name,age,address,education) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', [user.username,user.age,user.address,user.education])
    .then(()=>alert("insertFine"))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```